# how to manipulate CRLF in php?

Tags: php, regex, copy-paste, line-breaks, invalid-characters

Let us say I have string like below 
$comments =
Windows Embedded Compact (Windows CE) or Windows Server. Defunct Windows families include Windows 9x and Windows Mobile. [CR][LF]
 [CR][LF]
Microsoft introduced an operating environment named Windows on November 20, 1985, as a graphical operating system shell for MS-DOS in response to the growing interest in graphical user interfaces (GUIs).

**Note: [CR][LF] are manually added for the question. I found this issue when any user copy and paste any html content in the comments rich text area box we are observing these elements.**

Is there way where we can replace these with \n\r in PHP.

I tried something like this

```
$comments = preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n|\r\r|\n\n/", "<br />", $comments);
```

it didn't give me any proper result.

Comment: You can use `'~\R~'` and replace with `\n\r` if you plan to replace each newline sequence with `\n\r`.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. Please update the question stating what you need to replace with what. I do not know what "proper" result you expect.

Comment: Could you please give us some feedback on you tried and what was the result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it worked with the help of below regex.

Comment: Good. Still, future readers do not know what exactly your issue looked like.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. I will be more precise next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to replace any combinations of [CR] and [LF] by [CR][LF] (i.e. `\r\n`, not `\n\r`), try this:

```
$string = ".....[CR].....[LF]...[CR][LF].....[CR][CR].......[LF][LF].......";
$result = preg_replace('/\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n/', '\r\n', $string);
```

Comment: @Wiktor: Thanks - you are right. I'll update the example.

Comment: Still, it is not clear if your answer is correct or not, since the question is unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: If my string is having such kind of characters i want to escape them before sending the request to the API.Please let me know if my question is still unclear. I will improve myself in providing the right question